# Criar método de Impressão mais facilmente

Tags: c#, impressão

Tenho uma formulário pronto e preciso estanciar as variaveis nos campos certos, mas quero uma forma mais rapida e facil para poder fazer. Pois nao quero perder muito tempo fazendo os e.Graphics.DrawString pois demora muito tempo ajustando no lugar certo. Existe alguma ferramento ou ate mesmo algo que posso de primeira me mostrar as coordenadas x y ?

```
        Font fonte = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
        Font fonte2 = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);


        Bitmap jpg = Properties.Resources.Form2;
        Image newImage = jpg;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, 1, 1, newImage.Width, newImage.Height);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(txtNomePaciente.Text, fonte2, Brushes.Black, 290, 285);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(txtDtNasc.Text, fonte2, Brushes.Black, 330, 305);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(txtRgPaciente.Text, fonte2, Brushes.Black, 200, 325);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(txtNomeSolicitante.Text, fonte2, Brushes.Black, 225,            345);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(txtDtAtend.Text, fonte2, Brushes.Black, 330, 365);

        if (RbSim.Checked)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString("X", fonte, Brushes.Black, 260, 388);
        }
        else
            e.Graphics.DrawString("X", fonte, Brushes.Black, 600, 388);

        e.Graphics.DrawString(txtDias.Text, fonte2, Brushes.Black, 355, 385);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(CbUnid.Text, fonte2, Brushes.Black, 362, 425);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(txtTele.Text, fonte2, Brushes.Black, 337, 465);

        e.Graphics.DrawString(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd                      MMMMM                            yyyy"), fonte2, Brushes.Black, 359, 527);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), fonte2, Brushes.Black, 320, 830);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(txtNomePaciente.Text, fonte2, Brushes.Black, 320, 850);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(txtDtAtend.Text, fonte2, Brushes.Black, 330, 870);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(CbUnid.Text, fonte2, Brushes.Black, 350, 890);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(txtID, fonte2, Brushes.Black, 700, 205);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(txtID, fonte2, Brushes.Black, 700, 800);
```

Comment: Você tem algum código pronto que possa ser colocado na sua pergunta?

Comment: Assim, posso até colocar mas nao seria o ponto de melhorar o codigo, mas sim a facilitar a criação de formulario para impressão

Comment: Eu sei, mas está um pouco abstrato pra entender sua dúvida. Tendo código posso direcionar uma boa resposta pra você.